# How to upgrade this code to latest Mongo Java driver?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on this legacy application (7 years old). I have many methods that do the same thing that I am trying to upgrade to a newer MongoDB Java driver, but it won't compile.

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdatePrinter(Document printer) {
    printer.put(PRINTER_COLUMNS.updateDate,new Date());     
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("PRINTERS");
    printer.remove("_id");      
    Document query = new Document().append(PRINTER_COLUMNS.internal_id, printer.get(PRINTER_COLUMNS.internal_id));              
    WriteResult result = collection.update(query, printer, true, false);
    logger.debug("saveOrUpdatePrinter updeded records: " + result.getN());
}//
```

The error is:

> The method update(Document, Document, boolean, boolean) is undefined
> for the type MongoCollection<Document>

Why was this removed?

```
printer.remove("_id");
```

Also I would like to know how to do either update or save on the document in one go?

And what will be the proper way to update a single document in the new (MongoDB Java driver 4.7.0)?

Reading this code a little more seems like it was an attempt to do UPSERT operation (update or insert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions.

Q : **How to do either Update or Save on the Document in one go?**

-> MongoDB's `update` method updates the values in the existing document whereas the `save` method replaces the existing document with the document passed. Nothing happens in one go.

`update` method only updates which are specific fields which are modified by comparing the fields from the modified document with the original document whereas the `save` method updates/replaces the values of all the fields of an original document by the taking values from the modified document and setting the values into the original document.

Q : **What will be the proper way to update a single document in the new (Mongo Java driver 4.7.0)**

-> You should be using `updateOne(query, updates, options)` to update a single document on a MongoCollection object.

From [updateOne docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.6/usage-examples/updateOne/) :

> The method accepts a filter that matches the document you want to
> update and an update statement that instructs the driver how to change
> the matching document. The updateOne() method only updates the first
> document that matches the filter.
>
> To perform an update with the updateOne() method, you must pass a
> query filter and an update document. The query filter specifies the
> criteria for which document to perform the update on and the update
> document provides instructions on what changes to make to it.
>
> You can optionally pass an instance of UpdateOptions to the
> updateOne() method in order to specify the method's behavior. For
> example, if you set the upsert field of the UpdateOptions object to
> true, the operation inserts a new document from the fields in both the
> query and update document if no documents match the query filter.

Q : **Is it seems like it was an attempt to do UPSERT operation (Update or Insert) ?**

-> Yes, it's an upsert operation.

Q : **Why the code is trying to remove `_id` from document ?**

-> The `update` method will update the document if the document was found by `internal_id`. If the document was not found and also if there is no `_id` field in the document, then the mongoshell will consider it as a new document and will invoke `insert` method internally via the `update` method to insert the document. For the insertion to happen, that's why it was removed from document.

Just update the code to this.

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdatePrinter(Document printer) {   
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("PRINTERS");     
    Document query = new Document().append(PRINTER_COLUMNS.internal_id, printer.get(PRINTER_COLUMNS.internal_id));
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
    printer.put(PRINTER_COLUMNS.updateDate,new Date());
    UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(query, printer, options);             
    logger.debug("saveOrUpdatePrinter updated records: " + result.getModifiedCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update a document using the [MongoCollection#updateOne()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.7/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson,org.bson.conversions.Bson)) method

An example would be:

```
collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("1234")), Updates.set("date", new Date());
```